# Are any events fired when I click the X on chrome's input type = search element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, search, input

So I just decided to throw in an `<input type="search">` element on a page, and I see Chrome renders a nice little X icon that I can click on to clear the value. It looks like this icon can trigger the `change` event, but only when the `input` content has changed since the last `blur`.

Say I am handling `keyup` events to automatically render results as a user types. As they type, results are filtered (automatically firing some ajax during each `keyup` event). Then, when the user stops and clicks the X icon, I want to revert back to showing all results.

I can't seem to figure out how to handle this scenario. When the user starts with an empty box, they give it focus and start typing. However when they stop and click chrome's X button, `keyup` is not fired (duh). Furthermore, when they blur, the `change` event is not fired because the search input is in the same state as it was when it first received focus.

Are there any other events fired when someone clicks this little X icon? Do I have to handle `click` as well as `keyup`, or is there something more specific?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [onsearch event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdvxmhr.php) which is fired whenever the user searches or the search text is removed by pressing the `x`

Comment: What's the purpose of the onsearch event when the oninput event is also triggered?